# С веб-странички записывает в базу кракозябры, если ввожу данные на русском, на англ. - все отлично

Tags: java, кодировка, oracle, кириллица

*jsp-код* страницы:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
          <header>
            <div class='acLogo'>
                <p>Легкоатлетичний манеж </p>
                <p class="uabs">УАБС НБУ</p>            
            </div>

            <a href="\Manyezh\Gallery.jsp" class="button1">Галерея</a>     
        <a href="\Manyezh\RentObjectPage.jsp" class="button1">Вартість</a>       
        <a href="\Manyezh\ContactInformation.jsp" class="button1">Контактна інформація</a>
         <form action="ControllerServlet" method="post">


        <% Object isAdmin1 = request.getSession().getAttribute("isAdmin");
        if (isAdmin1 != null) {
           Boolean isAdmin =  (Boolean)isAdmin1 ; 
           if (isAdmin) {
        %>
        <input type="submit" value="Сторінка адміністратора" name="goToAdminPage" /> 
        <% }
        }
        %>
        <% Object isClient1 = request.getSession().getAttribute("isClient"); 
           if (isClient1 != null) {
           Boolean isClient = (Boolean)isClient1 ; 
           if (isClient) {
        %>
        <input type="submit" value="Зробити замовлення" name="goToOrders" />
        <% }
        }
        %>

        <% if (isAdmin1 == null && isClient1 == null) { %>

         <div class="logIn">
           <input type="text" name="login1" placeholder='login'/>

        <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder='password'/>

        <input type="submit" value="Вхід" name="goToAccount"/>

        <input type="submit" value="Реєстрація" name="goToRegistrationPage"/> 

        </div>


        <%
                }
        %>

        </form>
        </header>

        <h1>Сторінка Реєстрації</h1> 
        <form class="registerPage" action="ControllerServlet" method="post">    
        <table>   

            <p>Назва компанії</p>

        <input type="text" name="companyName" />

            <p>Адреса компанії</p>

        <input type="text" name="companyAddress" />

            <p>Посада</p>

            <input type="text" name="position"/>

            <p>Ім'я</p>

        <input type="text" name="firstname" />

            <p>Прізвище</p>

        <input type="text" name="surname" />

            <p>По батькові</p>

            <input type="text" name="patronymic"/>

            <p>Ваш мобільний</p>

            <input type="text" name="tel"/>

            <p>Електронна пошта</p>

            <input type="text" name="email"/>

            <p>Логін</p>

            <input type="text" name="login"/>

            <p>Пароль</p>

            <input type="text" name="password"/>

        <input class='btn' type="submit" name="toDoRegistration" value="Зареєструватися"/>

        <a id="copyright" href="/Manyezh/StartPage.jsp"> На головну </a>

        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Сервлет(не весь, но то, что касается регистрации есть):

```
package controller;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.Client;
import model.Orders;
import model.RentObject;


public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static Connection connect;  
    private static final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
    private static final String userName = "system";
    private static final String mypassword = "blink1994";
    private static final String className ="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            super.init();
            Class.forName(className);
            try {
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName, mypassword);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JDBC_Servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JDBC_Servlet.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, null, ex);
        }
    }   


    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

                    ForClient forClient = new ForClient();
                    ForAdmin forAdmin = new ForAdmin();

                    String buttonGoToRegistrationPage = request.getParameter("goToRegistrationPage");                                    
                    String buttonToDoRegistration = request.getParameter("toDoRegistration");
                    String buttonGoToAccount = request.getParameter("goToAccount");
                    String buttonGoToGallery = request.getParameter("goToPhoto");
                    String buttonGoToAdminPage = request.getParameter("goToAdminPage");   
                    String buttonToDoOrder = request.getParameter("toDoOrder");    
                    String buttonSubmitOrder = request.getParameter("SubmitOrder");                     
                    String goToOrders = request.getParameter("goToOrders"); 
                    String buttonClientInfo = request.getParameter("ClientInfo");                   
                    String deleteOrder = request.getParameter("deleteOrder");
                    String ChangeBtn = request.getParameter("Change");                    
                    String ChangeOrder = request.getParameter("ChangeOrder"); 
                    String toCost = request.getParameter("toCost");                     


                    if (goToOrders != null){

                    List<RentObject> rentObj =  forClient.dropDownList();
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("rentObj", rentObj);                    

                    response.sendRedirect("OrderPage.jsp");

                    }     

                    if (buttonGoToRegistrationPage != null){

                    response.sendRedirect("Registration.jsp");

                    } 

                    if (buttonToDoRegistration != null){

                    String companyName = request.getParameter("companyName");
                    String companyAddress = request.getParameter("companyAddress");
                    String position = request.getParameter("position");                    
                    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
                    String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
                    String patronymic = request.getParameter("patronymic");                    
                    String tel = request.getParameter("tel");
                    String email = request.getParameter("email"); 
                    String login = request.getParameter("login");                   
                    String password = request.getParameter("password");                      

                    forClient.registry(companyName,companyAddress,position,firstName,surname, patronymic,tel,email,login,password);
                    response.sendRedirect("StartPage.jsp");
                    }
```

Метод :

```
package controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import model.Client;
import model.Orders;
import model.RentObject;
import model.Staff;
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class ForClient {

                public  SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

                 void initSession(){
                    if (sessionFactory== null)
                        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(new File("C:\\Users\\Маклай\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Manyezh\\src\\java\\hibernate.cfg.xml")).buildSessionFactory();

                }

                public  void registry(String companyName,String companyAddress,String position,String firstName,String surname,String patronymic,String tel,String email,String login,String password) {

                this.initSession();

                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                session.beginTransaction(); 

                    Client cl = new Client();
                cl.setCompanyName(companyName);
                cl.setCompanyAddress(companyAddress);
                cl.setPosition(position);
                cl.setFirstName(firstName);
                cl.setSurname(surname);
                cl.setPatronymic(patronymic);
                cl.setTel(tel);
                cl.setEmail(email);
                cl.setLogin(login);
                cl.setPassword(password);


                session.save(cl);
                session.getTransaction().commit();
                session.close();  
                }
```

БД - *Oracle*, *sql-developer*, работаю в *netBeans* с *jee7*.

Comment: какая кодировка в БД?

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN

Comment: Nofate, CL8MSWIN1251

Comment: я так понимаю, у меня не совместимость кодировок, но переустанавливать базу ни времени, ни желание нет, какие есть еще варианты решения?

Comment: В своё время были варианты Oracle XE не поддерживающие юникод - только латиница. Если у вас такой вариант, то решения без переустановки сервера нет.

Comment: подскажите, как это проверить

Comment: кстати, проверил есть ли в библиотеке кодировка AL16UTF16, ответило, что есть, но вот как сменить ту, что есть на новую не получается

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте соответствие кодировок в базе и приложении - Java использует UTF-8 - лучший вариант, чтобы база тоже его использовала
2. Актуально если Tomcat - он присылает строки в ISO формате, их необходимо переконвертировать в UTF-8 при помощи ServletFilter.